# SQL Update Multiple Rows value based on same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

We have a table that contains all of our products.  In here is a column called UNITMEASURE.  This column is populated with values such as "EA, PR, PK, YD, etc".  Occasionally a 1 will get populated into this column.  I would like to run an update statement to change the 1's to whatever the other values are.

For example:

```
PRODUCT  UNITMEASURE
1234     1
1234     1
1234     PR
1234     1
1234     1
4321     1
4321     1
4321     EA
4321     1
4321     1
```

I want to be able to update the UNITMEASURE for all lines of PRODUCT 1234 to PR and PRODUCT 4321 to EA (from 1) with one query, but am completely stumped.  There are over 8,000 products that this could happen to, so I would want to lookup the UNITMEASURE <> '1' and update from that for each product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
update producttable
set UNITMEASURE = case WHEN PRODUCT = 1234
                       THEN = 'PR'
                       WHEN PRODUCT = 4321
                       THEN = 'EA'
                       ELSE = UNITMEASURE
                  END
```

for updated question

```
update producttable
set UNITMEASURE = PT2.UNITMEASURE
from  producttable PT
join (select UNITMEASURE, PRODUCT 
      from producttable
      UNITMEASURE <> 1) PT2 
  on PT.PRODUCT = PT2.PRODUCT
where PT.UNITMEASURE = 1
```

Comment: Just added a new note to the question:

There are over 8,000 products that this could happen to, so I would want to lookup the UNITMEASURE <> '1' and update from that for each product.

Comment: This is what I was looking for!  There was the Where clause missed in the select statement, but we're all human right? :)  Thanks!

Comment: @TripleNad I'm glad I could help you. If you saw a mistake in may solution please update may code to do it better ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
update yourtable
   set UNITMEASURE = (case when PRODUCT=1234 then 'PR'
                           when PRODUCT=4321 then 'EA'
                           else UNITMEASURE
                           end)
 where UNITMEASURE <> 1
```

Comment: Just added a new note to the question:

There are over 8,000 products that this could happen to, so I would want to lookup the UNITMEASURE <> '1' and update from that for each product.

Comment: @TripleNad Your original question stated that your are updating it from 1 so. The answer to that was right. I will edit it.

Comment: Understood, but I don't want to have to define 8,000 when/then statements for every single product we have that this could happen to. I am looking for a way to define the UNITMEASURE automatically based on the value of <> '1'

Comment: If I understood you right you want to change that UNITMEASURE just for the ones that is `<> '1'` right? If so this is the query you want. You can add more filters to decrease the amount of updates. But if your question is about change the value on the moment it is inserted then it will be a different thing to do. Is it the first or second option?

Comment: Yes, I do want to change the ones that are  <> '1', but if I have 1500 products currently in there with 1's, then I would need to define 1500 when/then statements with your method.

Comment: No, you are wrong. There is a `WHERE` avoiding the behavior you mention. If you have 1500 products and from these there are 1000 with `'1'` this `update` will only change those 500 left.

Comment: If it is in some master table then by query only you can do that. How is your schema

Comment: The behavior you mention only will be true WHITOUT the `where` clause

Comment: While this is resolved already, what would happen when product 6789 was introduced with UNITMEASURE of 1?  It would leave it at 1 because of the ELSE statement.  This is what I wanted to avoid was writing a when/then statement for every single product that is in the database.  Parado's solution was the one I was looking for.  Thanks for your help on this though.

Comment: No you are reading the update command in the wrong way. First if it is UNITMEASURE=1 it will never attend to the update command. So nothing would happen with it. If the where clause was UNITMEASURE<>1 for the product 6789 the it will chenge it to the UNITMEASURE that it already has like UNITMEASURE=UNITMEASURE.

Comment: Jorge, your query does the opposite of what the OP is asking.  He wants to update the records where the unitmeasure = '1', so that they end up with a value such as 'PR', 'EA', etc.  you are only updating rows where the unitmeasure <> '1', which are the rows that are already correct.

Comment: Well I've answred just that to him and He told me he want the opposite. Se my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Following query will not impact the other records which has UNITMEASURE <> '1'

It depends on your schema. If you have 1500 products it must be in some master table with some UNITMEASURE value. you can just write the sub query to get that.

```
 update yourtable
   set UNITMEASURE = (case when PRODUCT=1234 then 'PR'
                           when PRODUCT=4321 then 'EA'
                           else UNITMEASURE
                           end)
 where UNITMEASURE <> 1
```

Comment: Understood, but I don't want to have to define 8,000 when/then statements for every single product we have that this could happen to.  I am looking for a way to define the UNITMEASURE automatically based on the value of <> '1'

Comment: You want to update the UNITMEASURE column at the time of entry? if yes then you can use the trigger for insert.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the other answers only cover the scenario from your example.  Here is a more generalized query:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET unitmeasure = n.unitmeasure
FROM yourtable y
INNER JOIN yourtable n ON n.product = y.product
WHERE y.unitmeasure = '1'
AND n.unitmeasure <> '1'
```